# No Sequence of polynomials converging to $f(z)= \frac{1}{z}$ on given compact set $K$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

let $K=\left \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \frac{1}{2}\leq |z|\leq2 \right \}$. Then $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on an open neighbourhood of $K$.

use Maximum principal to show that there is no sequence $P_n$ of polynomials such that $P_n \to f$ uniformaly on $K$.

first please tell what it mean to say a function $f$ is holomorphic in open neighbourhood of compact set $K$.

Now in the question $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ has maximum value of $2$ on $K$. let $P_n \to f$

then it mean $\text{sup}_{z\in K}|P_n(z)-f(z)| \to 0$. from this how can i get contraduction . also i donot understand how can i use that sequence $P_n$ are polynomials.

any suggestion ??

Comment: "$f$ is holomorphic in open neighbourhood of compact set $K$" means "there is an open set $U$ containing $K$ on which $f$ is holomorphic".

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the maximum value of $P_n$ on $K$ occurs on $\{z: |z|=2\}$.

Comment: please explain a bit,as i am not geeting what you want to say

Comment: The idea is that if $P_n$ is (sufficiently, uniformly) close to $f$ on $K$, then the max modulus of $P_n$ on $K$ *will not* occur on $\{z: |z| = 2\}$, a contradiction.  You have to do some easy triangle inequality estimates to see this.

Comment: @fredgoodman but why maxi of $|P_n|$ occur at circle $|z|=2$? i know it will occur at boundary of $K$ .but why not on $|z|= \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: This is the point:  it is because $P_n$ extends to a holomorphic function in a neighborhood of $\{z : |z| \le 2\}$.   You apply max modulus with *that* set, not with $K$.

Comment: @fredgoodman to which function does $P_n$ extends in neighbourhood of $ \{ z:|z| \leq 2\}$? Runge theorm?

Comment: No theorem needed. The $P_n$ are polynomials.  They are entire functions.  The restriction of one of them to the disc $\{z: |z| \le 2\}$ takes it's max modulus on the boundary circle.